# Display checkbox input in mail body PHPmailer

Tags: php, html, arrays, string, phpmailer

first of all I tried to echo the result of my checkbox field and it shows ok. But, when I put the checkbox name inside the PHPmailer setting, my mail only shows the word array.

I know it got to do with the array result from the checkbox, but I've no idea how to put the result inside the mail body. Please give me some advice and explanation.

Here is my HTML checkbox code

```
<form method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <p>If yes, which type of disposable contact lens have you worn before?</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens[]"  value="Monthly"/> Monthly<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disposable_lens[]"  value="Daily Disposables"/> Daily Disposables<br>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is my PHP code to echo the result and it shows both value when checked

```
if(empty($_POST["disposable_lens"]))
{
    $error .= '<p><label class="text-danger">Disposable_lens is required</label></p>';
}
else
{
    $disposable_lens = clean_text($_POST["disposable_lens"]);
    echo $disposable_lens."</br>";
}
```

And here my PHPmailer body code that only display word "array" inside my mail and also shows an error when I clicked Submit button

```
$mail->Body = join('', array(
        "Outlet: ",
        $_POST['outlet'],
        "<br/>",
        "Full Name: ",
        $_POST['fullname'],
        "<br/>",
        "Email Address: ",
        $_POST['email'],
        "<br/>",
        "Phone Number:",
        $_POST['contact_no'],
        "<br/>",
        "Have you worn contact lens before?: ",
        $_POST['lenses'],
        "<br/>",
        "If yes, which type of disposable contact lens have you worn before?: ",
        ($_POST['disposable_lens']),
        "<br/>",
        "Appointment Date ",
        $_POST['date'],
        "<br/>",
        "Appointment Time ",
        $_POST['time']
        ));
```

Here's the echo result that showed both my checkbox value when been checked but in mail, only display the word "array".

[image]

Comment: I do not recommend putting form elements in email. It’s very unreliable. You’d be much better off sending a link to a web form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$_POST['disposable_lens']` is an array of all the checkbox values. When you convert an array to a string you just get `Array`. If you want a comma-separated list use `implode()`.

```
   "If yes, which type of disposable contact lens have you worn before?: ",
    implode(', ', $_POST['disposable_lens']),
```

Comment: FYI, `implode()` is the same as `join()`, which you used earlier in your code. So it seems like you already know about it.